# Bootstrap | Broken Events, drop down menu and slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a issue with the Bootstrap framework and I am not sure why, essentially the drop down menu and the slide show don't work in my 'timeline.html', and when I hook the paths up as much as possible in the shown example they work perfectly. Any help would be great guys, I have used the files in these links:

Timeline.html (file with the issue): https://www.dropbox.com/s/ao38yl03zmrqc5n/timeline.html?dl=0

Example Code which I based the other html file off: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i1owz94vtt62y13/Theme%20Template%20for%20Bootstrap.html?dl=0

The source files can be found on getbootstrap.com and they are the basic ones I believe.

Comment: Post this code in JSFiddle, or better yet, post the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the path for css and js files.

```
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"">
```

```
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure the css and js inside the `Bootstrap_files` folder and try.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <!-- saved from url=(0039)http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/ -->
        <html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="author" content="">
            <link rel="icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

            <title>Theme Template for Bootstrap</title>

            <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
            <link href="Bootstrap_files/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
            <link href="Bootstrap_files/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
            <link href="Bootstrap_files/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
            <link href="Bootstrap_files/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">

            <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
            <script src="Bootstrap_files/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js.download"></script>

            <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
          </head>
```